# How to click on required button with same class using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In a specific screen, there are three buttons(Advaced Mode, Next, Cancel) in one page with same input class under one div style.Using selenium webdriver, i have automate these.

Using Selenium Webdriver, i have to automate these. if i make use of xpath i can click on required button. But i dont want to depend on xpath, so i'm looking for altenate solution like css related identifications.

Advanced Mode: input class="submit" type="button" value="Advanced Mode" onclick="goAdvance()"

Next: input class="submit" type="button" value="Next" onclick="saveProfile()"

Cancel: input class="submit" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="goHome(1)

Comment: [link](http://www.flickr.com/photos/90591961@N02/9512158496/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a read: http://sauceio.com/index.php/2010/01/selenium-totw-css-selectors-in-selenium-demystified/

Generally...
Advanced Mode: input[value="Advanced Mode"]

Next: input[value="Next"]

Cancel: input[value="Cancel"]

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you can select by any of the attributes.  `input[value="XXXX"]`, replacing XXXX, will work.  You could also to `.submit[value="XXXX"]`

Comment: Lets say if i want to click on "Advanced". Can you modify the below statement accordingly.
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".submit"))

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".submit[value='Advanced']"));`